# Multiline substitution to obtain a tree view

Tags: bash, sed, tree, multiline, substitution

I have a bash script that generates the following output from a certain input using `sed` and `awk:

```
# ├── CHILDA1
# │  └── CHILDB1
# │  └── CHILDB2
# │  └── CHILDB3
# │  └── CHILDB4
# │  └── CHILDB5
# │  └── CHILDB6
# │     └── CHILDC1
# │     └── CHILDC2
# │  └── CHILDB7
# ├── CHILDA2
# └──────────────
```

Is there a way to replace the nest connectors, if they are not the last one, in order to obtain something like this?

```
# ├──┐CHILDA1
# │  ├── CHILDB1
# │  ├── CHILDB2
# │  ├── CHILDB3
# │  ├── CHILDB4
# │  ├── CHILDB5
# │  ├──┐CHILDB6
# │  │  ├── CHILDC1
# │  │  └── CHILDC2
# │  └── CHILDB7
# ├── CHILDA2
# └──────────────
```

The first output has been obtained with simple single lines substitutions, I guess the second one needs to check for the row above at the same column (character position). I don't know how `tree` handles this, but the result I would like to obtain is very similar.

Unicode characters obtained from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_Drawing

Comment: replacing `└` by `├` is trivial but adding `┐` in the correct places isn't. It's probably easier to modify your `sed` `awk` code upstream than post-processing the output

Comment: @Fravadona the point is that not all `└` must be substituted: the character  should be replaced for all but the last child **of a nest**. The upstream code is useless in this case as it has no idea of whether an item is the last child of a nest (like CHILDC2) or not. It kinda works like markdown headings as it only replaces a certain amount of `X` with the corresponding nest indentation

Comment: Is this a directory structure? Why can't you use `tree`?

Comment: generally speaking it *is* possible in `awk` to perform this kind of logic (ie, 'last line' gets special/different treatment) so I'm with Fravadona ... push this additional coding requirement back into the upstream `awk` code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easier to process the file from the bottom up. This can be achieved using `tac`.

Through `@flags`, the following tracks the position of children whose parent has not yet been encountered.

```sh
tac |
perl -CSD -Mutf8 -pe'
   if ( /[└├]/ ) {
      my $i = $-[0];         # Position of the match.
      substr($_, $i, 1, "├") if $flags[$i];
      $flags[$i] = 1;

      my $j = $i+3;          # Position of its children.
      substr($_, $j, 1, "┐") if $flags[$j];
      $flags[$j] = 0;

      while ( $i-- ) {
         substr($_, $i, 1, "│") if $flags[$i];
      }
   }
' |
tac
```

Output

```
# ├── CHILDA1
# │  ├── CHILDB1
# │  ├── CHILDB2
# │  ├── CHILDB3
# │  ├── CHILDB4
# │  ├── CHILDB5
# │  ├──┐CHILDB6
# │  │  ├── CHILDC1
# │  │  └── CHILDC2
# │  └── CHILDB7
# ├── CHILDA2
# └──────────────
```

---

All in Perl:

```sh
perl -CSD -Mutf8 -e'
   my @lines = reverse <>;

   for ( @lines ) {   
      if ( /[└├]/ ) {
         my $i = $-[0];         # Position of the match.
         substr($_, $i, 1, "├") if $flags[$i];
         $flags[$i] = 1;

         my $j = $i+3;          # Position of its children.
         substr($_, $j, 1, "┐") if $flags[$j];
         $flags[$j] = 0;

         while ( $i-- ) {
            substr($_, $i, 1, "│") if $flags[$i];
         }
      }
   }

   print reverse @lines;
'
```

Comment: Nice, the `┐` of `CHILDA1` is missing but +1 nevertheless

Comment: @Fravadona, yeah, I know, but I didn't care. However, the perfectionist in me ended up addressing that issue before seeing your comment :)

Comment: Fixed a bug or two.